# Relative Markersize in Matlab plots

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot a matrix where each element is in one out of two states. (ising model..)

Now, I would like to have one state colored and the other one white. That works using

```
[i,j] = find(S);
figure(gcf);
plothandle = scatter(i,j);
axis([0 nNodes+1 0 nNodes+1]);
```

when S holds the Spins and one state is equal to 0. (find returns a matrix of only non-zero elements)

To have a useful plot, the sizes of the markers should be 1x1 in RELATIVE coordinates. So if the whole matrix S would be in a state non-zero, everything would be colored.

However, it seems like Matlab only allows MarkerSizes in points or inches. How could I solve this?

One idea I had was, that I find out the point-size of the axes and then can easily calculate how big my markers should be. Then I would have to create a callback function if I want to zoom in and so on. Also, I have not yet found a way (without the image acq. toolbox) to find out the absolute size of my axes.

To clarify what I want: How could I plot a chessboard using a matrix with 1 for black and 0 for white fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For displaying data of this sort I generally prefer [IMAGE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/image.html) or [IMAGESC](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imagesc.html) to [PCOLOR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/pcolor.html) since [PCOLOR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/pcolor.html) won't display the last row and column of the matrix when using faceted shading (the default). Also, [IMAGE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/image.html) and [IMAGESC](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imagesc.html) flip the y axis so the image more intuitively matches what you think of when looking at a *matrix* (i.e. rows start from 1 at the top). You can visualize your matrix like this:

```
S = round(rand(20));       %# Sample 20-by-20 matrix of ones and zeroes
imagesc(S);                %# Plot the image
colormap([1 1 1; 0 0 0]);  %# Set the colormap to show white (zero elements) and
                           %#   black (non-zero elements)
```

And here's a sample image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just as a suggestion, you can try using `pcolor` instead of `scatter' Example:

```
pcolor(hadamard(20))
colormap(gray(2))
axis ij
axis square
```